# Drawing lines in HTML5/JS webGL using user input from text field

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, webgl

I am currently working on project in HTML and js where I have a simple canvas and two text fields (x and y) with a button called "Draw".

Trying to get it to draw a line via the user's entered x and y intercepts onto the canvas with onclick.

The function I am calling with onclick is generateImage().

I can tell that the text fields are in fact receiving the users info. I tested this by using a window.alert to show a pop up with the info (i have it commented out for now).

At first I thought it had to do with how i set up my button, but after asking around I think this cannot be true:

```
<button type="button" onclick="generateImage()"> DRAW LINE!</button>
```

I have no more errors on the console.

I even had my professor look at it and he said that it looked alright. I am beginning to think that this is a problem somewhere else within the program. I am sure I am either a) being stupid/frustrated or b) seriously over looking something.

Here is some of my code.

One last thing. var x0=... and var y0 =...  I am aware that I will get a slope of zero and a line length of zero because they are the same..

My professor has told us to use this algorithm even thought it doesn't make sense to me. I would like to mention that I have also tried to hard code the x and y values and it still does not work.

Thanks

***HTML***

```
<body>
    <form action="demo_form.asp">
        X = <input name="X Value" type="text" id="Xvalue"><br>
        Y = <input name="Y Value" type="text" id="Yvalue"><br>
    </form> 
    <button type="button" onclick="generateImage()"> DRAW LINE!</button>
    <p>Click "DRAW LINE" button to draw the line with custom X and Y coords</p>
<canvas id="gl-canvas" width="512", height="512">
<pre>No Support... :(</pre>
</canvas>

</body>


***JS***

function generateImage()
{

        var x0 = document.getElementById('Xvalue').value;
        var y0 = document.getElementById('Yvalue').value;
        var x1 = document.getElementById('Xvalue').value;
        var y1 = document.getElementById('Yvalue').value;
    //  window.alert(x0);
    //  window.alert(y0);


        var slope = (y1-y0)/(x1-x0);

        for (var i=0; i<x1-x0; i++){

            var y = (slope*i)+y0;
            var x = x0 + i;

            myImage.setPixel(x,y, RED);
        }

}

function glInit(canvas)     
{
    //makes our GL instance
    gl=WebGLUtils.setupWebGL(canvas);
    //gets and initializes our vertex and fragment shaders
    program = initShaders(gl, "vertex-shader", "fragment-shader");
    //sets the resulting shader program to use
    gl.useProgram(program);
}

window.onload=function init()
{

    var canvas = document.getElementById("gl-canvas");


    glInit(canvas);

    myImage=new Image(canvas);


    myImage.setImageSize(700, 350);
    myImage.clearImage();


    generateImage(myImage);

    renderImage(myImage);   

}

function renderImage(myImage)
{
    points=[]; 
    colors=[]; 

    for (var i=0; i<pixels.length; i++)
    {
        var y=Math.floor(i/myImage.width);
        var x=i-(y*myImage.width);

        colors.push(myImage.getPixel(x, y));

        x/=myImage.width/2;
        y/=myImage.height/2;

        x-=1.0;
        y-=1.0;


        points.push(vec3(x, y, 0.0, 0.0));
    }

    gl.clearColor(0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 1.0);
    gl.viewport(0, 0, myImage.width, myImage.height);

    var posBufferID=gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBufferID);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(points), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    program.vPositionA=gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vPosition");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vPosition, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vPositionA);


    var colBufferID=gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colBufferID);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, flatten(colors), gl.STATIC_DRAW);


    program.vColorA=gl.getAttribLocation(program, "vColor");
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vColorA, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(program.vColorA);


    render(program, colBufferID, posBufferID);
}

function render(program, colBufferID, posBufferID)    
{
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, colBufferID);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vColorA, 4, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, posBufferID);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(program.vPositionA, 3, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS, 0, points.length);
}
```

Comment: Did you set `gl_PointSize` in your vertex shader?

Comment: What a great question looking forward the answer :)